# For any square matrix $A$, are there infinitely many square matrices $B$ having same size such that $AB = BA$?

Tags: matrices

It's easy to prove when the matrices are 2 by 2. but it's hard for 'any' square matrices.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly it's false if the base field is finite. If the field is infinite then $xI$ with $x$ an element in the field and $I$ the appropriately sized identity matrix is such a collection of matrices that commute with every other square matrix of that size.

Answer (score 3):

A matrix $A$ commutes with any matrix of the form $p(A)$ where $p$ is a univariate polynomial with coefficients in the field of scalars, hence if the field is infinite, the answer is yes.